# Need help on stop training of Keras network

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I have the following question. When we teach the Keras NN, we have something like

```
    earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', patience=30, verbose=0, mode='auto')

results = model.fit_generator(
    Generator(train_ids, 
        batch_size = TRAINING_BATCH_SIZE), 
    steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH, # fill_in? 
    epochs = MAX_TRAIN_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=Generator(valid_ids, 
        batch_size = VALIDATION_BATCH_SIZE),
    validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, # fill_in?
    callbacks=[#checkpoint, # Commented as Kaggle does not save
        earlyStopping #, plot_losses
        ])
```

Now, this code snippet will stop when loss stop improving, but... 
Let's say, it goes like 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6
Then, when it stops, will my NN be the one that produced 0.5 (best) or 0.6 (last)?

In other words, should I keep testing the loss every epoch, and if a new min. reached, to save the NN, in order to get the best one? Or is there a way of doing it automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: According to the documentation ([https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping]), setting `restore_best_weights` controls which model weights are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is:

**1. how to save the best checkpoint?**

you can either save manually or use keras callback, but either way, you need some metric to choose the best weiths.

> keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss',
>   verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto',
>   period=1)

**So, Do I need keep evaluating my model on validation dataset to find out the best weights?**

It depends on how you choose the best weights. Usually we want the weights perform best on validation dataset, so you need periodically evaluate your model on validation dataset, otherwise you just don't know .